# UDP Server HashMap iteration of clients

Tags: java, udp, hashmap

I have a UDP server and one of the operations is to send a message to all clients that have joined. The server stores a record of clients in a HashMap.

To I need to create a method that can create and send datapackets to all the clients stored in the Hash. I've read up on it, but I still don't quite get how I would use the code shown below.

how can I loop through the hashmap and create unique packets to send for each element/record.. (I've looked at the foreach interator below, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
 System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

the best I can come up with is this

```
private void sendToAll(InetAddress clientIP, int clientPort, String message, String        fromUserName) {
for (Object key : cHASH.keySet())
{
Object value = cHASH.get(key);
//System.out.print(value);
//split value
//clientIP = [0]
//clientPort = [1]
//serverResponse(clientIP,ClientPort);
}
}
```

Comment: I assume this is something akin to sarcasm. I'd bounty it but I have to wait 2 days and this is due tommorow, so if anyone can help thats great, if not, I'll take it on the chin.

Answer (score 0):

This is very sloppy, even for me. But it worked so thanks guys :)
Open to suggestions for the Client to client method

```
         for (Object key : cHASH.keySet())
    {
        Object value = cHASH.get(key);
        Object[] newArr = ((String) value).split(",");
        System.out.print("element 0 "+newArr[0]);
        clientPort = Integer.parseInt((String) newArr[1]);
        //clientIP = (InetAddress) newArr[0];
        //clientIP = (InetAddress) newArr[1];
         InetAddress.getByName((String) newArr[1]);

        try {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        buf = sudMessage.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sPacket = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,
                clientIP, clientPort);
        serverSocket.send(sPacket);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }   


    }
```